# Be notified when replayed request has a response

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I try to be notified with no success (using an eventListner, a Callback or anything else) when a request replayed by `BackgroundSync.Queue` "DidReplay" (only the request, not the entire queue).

The point is that I need to get the server response to alter the incoming replaying requests in `requestWillReplay` depending of this response.

Also, I tried to intercept the request using:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {...})
```

but it doesn't work, I only intercept requests from the client.

Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to already be familiar with using `workbox.backgroundSync.Queue`'s [`callbacks.requestWillReplay()`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/workbox.backgroundSync.Queue) to modify the request prior to it being retried. That's the only callback that's currently supported.

If you're asking for more functionality beyond that, your best bet is to file a [feature request](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/new) against Workbox with the specific requirements.